# Setting Firestore security rules with Collections generated at runtime

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My Firestore database creates a new Collection whenever a new user Signs Up to my app. The name of the Collection is the username of the new user. I wanted to make the documents inside this collection to have restricted write access.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /User1/{info} {
      allow read: if signedIn();
      allow write: if isOwner(User1);
    }

    function signedIn() {
        return request.auth != null;
    }

    function isOwner(userId) {
      return request.auth.uid == userId;
    }    
  }
}
```

This works if the current user is `User1` but is not applicable to any new user that signs up. How do I add this Firestore Security Rule to every new user?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to have a collection per user.  Consider instead using a document per user using their uid, then subcollections under that as needed.

Comment: The only problem is that I am using Flutter for my app and I can't figure out how to access a subcollection in Flutter.

Comment: You should be able to reach into a subcollection using some method on DocumentReference, probably called collection().

Answer (score 4):

I notice that the first rule matches to `/User1/{info}`, meaning it will match any path in the collection `User1`. Instead, if you use brackets, this value becomes a wildcard, meaning the match will work for any value. Check out the examples in the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) for more information.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{username}/{info} {
      allow read: if signedIn();
      allow write: if isOwner(username);
    }

    function signedIn() {
        return request.auth != null;
    }

    function isOwner(userId) {
      return request.auth.uid == userId;
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have other Collections made during run time which do not store User info but something else. I wanted to apply different rules to those collections but doing this won't allow me to do that.

Comment: Then you should add separate rules for those collections.